# Proof that $\bigcup\mathscr F\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr G$, when every element of $\mathscr F$ a subset is of every element of $\mathscr G$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying for my exam of Logic later this week and I came across this question:

> Suppose that $\mathscr{F} \subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ and $\mathscr{G} \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ so that every element of $\mathscr{F}$ a subset is of every element of $\mathscr{G}$. Then applies $\bigcup\mathscr{F} \subseteq \bigcap \mathscr{G}$.

I think that this is a very obvious theorem but I can't find any easy and clear why of proofing it. Is there anyone who can help me?

Note: $\bigcup\mathscr{F}$ and $\bigcap\mathscr{F}$ are in our course defined as:

$$\bigcup\mathscr{F} = \{x\in X\mid\exists A\in\mathscr{F}\text{ s.t. } x \in A\}$$

$$\bigcap\mathscr{F} = \{x\in X\mid\forall A\in\mathscr{F}\text{ s.t. } x \in A\}$$

Comment: It is enough to show that every $Y\in\mathcal F$ is a subset of $\cap\,\mathcal G$. This is true by hypothesis, and so $\cap\,\mathcal G$ contains all the sets $Y\in\mathcal F$, hence their union, which is $\cup\,\mathcal F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \bigcup \mathscr{F}$. Then there exists some $A \in \mathscr{F}$ such that $x \in A$.

Let $B$ be any set from $\mathscr{G}$. By assumption, $A \subseteq B$. So $x \in B$. As $B \in \mathscr{G}$ was arbitrary, $x \in \bigcap \mathscr{G}$.

As $x$ was arbitrary, $\bigcup \mathscr{F} \subseteq \bigcap \mathscr{G}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed a very clear proof.

Comment: @George: Please refrain from stylistic edits like this. Not to mention that `\cup` to `\bigcup` is a losing battle on this site.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Show that $\bigcup\scr F$ is a subset of every element of $\scr G$, then conclude it is a subset of $\bigcap\scr G$. Remember that taking a union (or intersections) of subsets of some $A$, will result in a subset of $A$.